# Is there any way to remove an object that was created by an if statement from an ArrayList with another if statement?

Tags: java, arraylist

sorry if the code looks messy.

Newbie here.
I'm trying to get the user to remove an object of type App based on their input and the  ArrayList only accepts an object of type 'App'. However, I can't remove it because I created an object of type App in an if statement and I don't know how to access it. Is there any way I can remove and edit the objects created by a different if statement with an else if?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here



Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);



System.out.println("Enter your option from the list below");
System.out.println("1.App Store");
System.out.println("2.Customer stuff");
int input = myScan.nextInt();

if (input == 1){
    wholeSystem();
}


}





public static void wholeSystem()

{
    boolean choice = true;
    int input2 = 0;
    Shop appStore = new Shop(new ArrayList<App>());  
    while (choice == true)

            {



    Scanner myScan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter another option from the list below");
    System.out.println("1. Add new App details");
    System.out.println("2. Delete App details");
    System.out.println("3. Edit App details");
    System.out.println("4. List App details");
    System.out.println("5. Search App details");
    System.out.println("6. Quit");
    input2 = myScan2.nextInt(); 

    if (input2 == 6)
    {
        System.out.println("You have exited.");
         break;
    }

    else if (input2 == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("You have selected feature "+input2+".");
        Scanner myScan3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        App myObj = new App();
        System.out.println("Please enter the app name:");
        myObj.setAppName(myScan3.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please enter the developer name:");
        myObj.setDeveloperName(myScan3.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please enter the app's function:");
        myObj.setAppFunction(myScan3.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please enter the app's type");
        myObj.setType(myScan3.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please enter the app's cost:");
        myObj.setCost(myScan3.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Please enter the app's popularity:");
        myObj.setPopularity(myScan3.nextInt());
        System.out.println(myObj.getAppName()+myObj.getDeveloperName());
        appStore.addApp(myObj);




File AppStore = new File("AppStore");        
try{

BufferedWriter out;

out = new BufferedWriter ( new FileWriter(AppStore,true));


out.write(myObj.getAppName());
out.newLine();
out.write(myObj.getDeveloperName());
out.newLine();
out.write(myObj.getAppFunction());
out.newLine();
out.write(myObj.getType());
out.newLine();
out.write (String.valueOf(myObj.getCost()) );
out.newLine();
out.write(String.valueOf(myObj.getPopularity()) );
out.newLine();
out.write("========================================================");
out.newLine();
//Close the output stream
out.close();
}
catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }    
    }

    else if (input2 == 2)
    {
        int choiceInput = 0;
        System.out.println("You have selected feature "+input2+". Which app do you want deleted?");
        // here's where I tried to remove an object 
        appStore.printApps();
        choiceInput = myScan2.nextInt();
        appStore.deleteApp(choiceInput); with user input
```

Here's the shop class where I created the ArrayList.
    public class Shop {

```
private ArrayList<App> apps = new ArrayList<App>();



public Shop(ArrayList apps)
{
    this.apps = apps;
}

public ArrayList<App> getApps(){return apps;}

public void setApps(ArrayList<App>apps){this.apps = apps;}

public void addApp(App app){apps.add(app);}

public void deleteApp(App app){apps.remove(app);}
```

Comment: ... and what doesn't work? error message, stack trace, or description of behavior please. Note that you are calling deleteApp with an integer argument but your declarations sa you are supposed to pass an App.

Comment: It says an int is incompatible with app and that it cannot be converted. And yes, I'm trying to call it with an integer because I want the user to be able to enter a number into the scanner and delete an object from the arraylist based on the number given.

Comment: see my answer below, it doesn't take much more code to be able to delete apps based on their index in the ArrayList, since Arraylist supports that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, you just need to add another method to your Shop class:

```
public void deleteApp(int index){apps.remove(index);}
```

Right now you only support deleting by object reference, but the underlying ArrayList can also delete by index. If you expose that interface, your main code would work...

Edit: I earlier had Integer instead of int. That's an Object, so it would try to remove a matching object. To remove by index, I need to declare this with int and let Java box/unbox if you pass in an Integer.

Comment: Although it allows me to run the code, when I tried to remove an object it was still present in the ArrayList.Also, it says "Suspicious call to Java.util.Collection.remove: Given object cannot contain instances of Integer (expected App)".

Comment: @user3479469 please see edit. Changing Integer to int in my declaration makes a difference here.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can confirm that it's working perfectly! Really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score -1):

change the

> public static void wholeSystem()

signature to this :

```
public static List<App> wholeSystem()
```

then :

```
List<App> appList = new ArrayList<App>();   
if (input == 1){
   appList = wholeSystem();
}
```

then you can remove anyApp after the if (input == 1) block ~

if you are trying to delete the app using its index position inside the list do the following :

```
public void deleteApp(int index){
    App removedApp = apps.remove(index);
}
```

take note that above remove method also return the Object so you can do whatever you want with it ~